# Xcode-Submit score to GameCenter

Tags: ios, xcode, center, game-center

I have this code for submitting my score to game center however whenever i submit the score inside game center it says my score is 0. I am not sure how this happened? I also have imported the GameKit framework.

```
-(IBAction)submitScore{
    if (highscore>0) {
        GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"MyLeaderBoardID"] autorelease];

        scoreReporter.value = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:highscore] longLongValue];
        NSLog(@"posted");
        NSLog(@"%i",highscore);

        [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"failed!!!");
                NSLog(@"%i",highscore);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Succeded");
            }
        }];
    }
```

I also have this code for signing in:

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"authintication success");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"authintication failed");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game Center Disabled"
                                                        message:@"For Game Center make sure you have an account and you have a proper device connection."
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}];

self.currentLeaderBoard = @"MyLeaderBoardID";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference purposes, what is your score?

You should have two different variables to read in your old score and your new score. If your new score is greater than your old score, you want that if statement to be set to true. Having it set to be greater than zero will have it constantly change every time the user has a score greater than 0.